# MacOS Python 3.7 virtualenv fails?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

My system is running MacOS and Homebrew and it recently updated to Python 3.7.

Now, just creating a new virtualenv and trying to use it fails.

FYI, I don't actually need Python 3.7. I didn't upgrade on purpose. I'd prefer the latest stable, supported version, but of course, I want the basics working.

```
➜  rm -rf ~/.virtualenvs/test
➜  python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/test
➜  vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/test python
zsh: /usr/local/bin/vex: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory

➜  python3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 29 2018, 20:13:13) 
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/vex` file has this as the first line: `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6`; it's called [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and it points operating system to the interpreter to run the script. You've uninstalled `python3.6` so OS cannot find said interpreter. You need to reinstall `vex` with `python3.7`.